# Platinum Electrodes

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

In industry, numerous companies state that they use platinum electrodes for the purpose of electrolysis. My question is: are these electrodes pure platinum or could they also be, for example, another element/ compound coated in platinum such as platinum coated titanium mesh?

If they are about 100% platinum, why not use platinum coated titanium mesh in industry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, as you mentioned, platinum coated titanium meshes are used (or sheets). I am not aware of any application where pure platinum electrodes are demanded (for electrolysis).